# Accessing C++ variables in QML loaded in QQuickWidget with signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a C++ class, `WidgetEIS`, that inherits from QWidget and contains a QML view loaded using QQuickWidget.

The class has a property `modeEIS` defined using `Q_PROPERTY`.

I want to update a QML variable based on changes in the C++ class.

Simplified code:

```cpp
class WidgetEIS : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int modeEIS READ modeEIS WRITE setModeEIS NOTIFY modeEISChanged FINAL)
public:
    // ... other members

signals:
    void modeEISChanged();

private:
    // ... other members
};

WidgetEIS::WidgetEIS(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    eisWidget = createQQuickWidget("MfdWidgetLeft", "qrc:/qml/WindowMFD/EIS/EIS.qml", 0, 57, 150, 683);
}
```

```qml
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Rectangle
{
    id: containerEIS
    width: 150
    height: 683
    visible: true
   
    property int modeEIS: 1
}
```

Comment: There are tons of examples and documentation explaining how to integrate C++ with QML. Which of these have you tried? Btw, using both CWidgets and QQuick isn't good idea.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the outcome of the above example and what do you expect?

Comment: Suppose I am able to emit modeEISChanged signal in C++. I want to update the modeEIS variable in the qml too

Comment: Why isn't that a good idea @folibis?

Comment: @GrecKo, first of all, it violates the rules of Occam. You can build the same based on either QtQuick or QWidgets without mixing them. Technically you have additional thread(s) of QtQuick graph which probably doesn't make your program faster.

Comment: Some things are easily doable in Qt Quick and not in QWidgets, when adding new functionality to an existing QWidgets application, doing it in Qt Quick can be a sensible approach. The Qt Company is encouraging this pattern to make Qt Quick more widely used.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html You should really study that, just study, it's not many pages. After that you can probably fix your code, or if not, you can ask a question which maybe makes more sense than this.

Comment: Thanks alot everyone for your time and responses. I am trying be as simple as possible because my situation  is complicated, My QMainWindows has Widgets components i use classes to create those widget like above (a class to load QML component to add multiple functionalities and reduce complexity), QPushbutton, which changes values in classes like WidgetEIS which emits a signal (as expected) i want to change to qml properties i loaded qml in QQuickwidget(shown above)